# How not to display a field from a table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Such a problem. I have a DTO in which the fields of the tables **boat_cards** and **engines** are combined. Now I want to get data from table **engines** excluding the **cardid** field. The option with the **@JsonIgnore** annotation is not suitable, since this field may need to be displayed when querying the **engines** table itself Here is my code:

DAO class:

```
@Repository
public interface EnginesDao extends JpaRepository<Engines, Integer> {

    List<Engines> findAllByCardidCardid(Integer cardid);

    @Query(value = "SELECT engid, engname, engvin, engpwr, recdate FROM gims.engines  where cardid = :cardid",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Engines> findAllByCardidQuery(@Param("cardid") Integer cardid);

}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class EnginesServiceImpl implements EnginesService{

    @Autowired
    private EnginesDao enginesDao;

    @Override
    public List<Engines> getAllByCardidQuery(Integer id) {
        return enginesDao.findAllByCardidQuery(id);
    }
}
```

DTO class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BoatCardsDto extends BoatCards implements Serializable {

    private List<Engines> engines;


    public BoatCardsDto(BoatCards boatCards, List<Engines> engines) {
        this.cardid = boatCards.getCardid();
        this.regNum = boatCards.getRegNum();
        this.tiketNum = boatCards.getTiketNum();
        this.boatName = boatCards.getBoatName();
        this.boatType = boatCards.getBoatType();
        this.boatYear = boatCards.getBoatYear();
        this.boatVin = boatCards.getBoatVin();
        this.parkingPlace = boatCards.getParkingPlace();
        this.saCategory = boatCards.getSaCategory();
        this.boatLength = boatCards.getBoatLength();
        this.boatWidth = boatCards.getBoatWidth();
        this.boatHeight = boatCards.getBoatHeight();
        this.bodyMaterial = boatCards.getBodyMaterial();
        this.boatPayload = boatCards.getBoatPayload();
        this.passengersNum = boatCards.getPassengersNum();
        this.serviceLife = boatCards.getServiceLife();
        this.engineNum = boatCards.getEngineNum();
        this.owner = boatCards.getOwner();
        this.agent = boatCards.getAgent();
        this.note = boatCards.getNote();
        this.engines = engines;
    }

    public List<Engines> getEngines() {
        return engines;
    }

    public void setEngines(List<Engines> engines) {
        this.engines = engines;
    }
}
```

and my exception is:

```
2023-01-26T18:02:10.206+03:00 ERROR 19892 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
[Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
Unable to find column position by name: cardid; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
```

My engine entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "engines")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Engines {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "engid")
    Integer engid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cardid")
    BoatCards cardid;

    @Column(name = "engname")
    String engname;

    @Column(name = "engvin")
    String engvin;

    @Column(name = "engpwr")
    String engpwr;

    @Column(name = "recdate")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    Timestamp recdate;

}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to remove the `cardid` property from the response or want help fixing the exception?

Comment: @T4puSD I am trying to remove the cardid from the response